# Multi-website redirects to main domain

Tags: magento2.4, multi-website, redirect-url, multidomain

In the same Magento instance I've configured two different *Websites* with only one *Store* and two *Store Views* for each Store.

Website 1 -> Store 1 -> Store View 1

Website 1 -> Store 1 -> Store View 2

Website 2 -> Store 2 -> Store View 3

Website 2 -> Store 2 -> Store View 4

and following this guide (https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/multi-sites/ms-nginx.html?lang=en) to *Set up multiple websites with Nginx*

Now, if I try to navigate:

domain1.mg -> OK!

domain1.mg/storeview1 -> OK!

domain1.mg/storeview2 -> OK!

domain2.mg -> **KO! It redirects to domain1.mg/storeview1** (default storeview)

domain2.mg/storeview3 -> OK!

domain2.mg/storeview4 -> OK!

why this behavour?

Comment: Please check the base url for this second store, 
Go into the store->configuration->general->web and then switch your store view and then Open the base urls tabs and check all the url in that Store view if its seems to be fine then Go into the core_config_data table and then check the base url for all these stores.